# How are GOARCH and GOOS used during go toolchain compilation?

Tags: go

I am trying to reconcile why [make.bash](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/make.bash) accepts GOARCH, GOOS and other target variables when it also supports cross compiling to all supported architectures [by default](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5). I am compiling this for amd64/linux but will be using the compiler to cross-compile apps for arm/linux in an embedded context. Buildroot builds Go with the following command

```
cd /builddir/build/host-go-1.10.2/src && 
    GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/builddir/host/lib/go-1.4.3 
    GOROOT_FINAL=/builddir/host/lib/go 
    GOROOT="/builddir/build/host-go-1.10.2" 
    GOBIN="/builddir/build/host-go-1.10.2/bin" 
    GOARCH=arm 
    GOARM=7 
    GOOS=linux 
    CC=/usr/bin/gcc 
    CXX=/usr/bin/g++ 
    GO_ASSUME_CROSSCOMPILING=1 
    CC_FOR_TARGET="/builddir/host/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" 
    CXX_FOR_TARGET="/builddir/host/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" 
    CGO_ENABLED=1 
    ./make.bash
```

Which works and goes on to build other apps just fine. My question is why are these target variables relevant at this stage? Wouldn't that only be relevant to the applications being compiled with this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go compiler and linker are Go programs. `make.bash` needs to know which architecture and which operating system to build the Go toolchain for.

See [Downloads - The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/dl/) for examples of the different architectures and operating systems.

See [Installing Go from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source).

Comment: Isn't it building both for amd64/linux in this case? The program built by this command is what targets arm/linux in its subsequent builds.

Comment: A special build of the tool chain is not required to cross compile.

Comment: I figured out the disconnect. Go for the host arch is being generated since that is required to finally generate the cross-compiled toolchain. If I set GOHOSTARCH=arm it fails mid way through because toolchain1 isn't in a usable format. While bin/go was amd64 it was only an intermediate step, bin/linux_arm/go was the final target which I missed.